# How can I get actions logs in the script?

Tags: bash

I am a new at this so please be patiant.

I have a script that I did not write (not that advance, maybe one day) and I need it to output logs in var/logs.

Can anyone please help wiht it please?

I need to know that all the actions are completed in that script.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# copy the old database to a timestamped copy
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%d)
REPORT_EMAIL=user@domain.com

# backup Spamassassin bayes db
sa-learn -p /usr/mailcleaner/etc/mailscanner/spam.assassin.prefs.conf --siteconfigpath /usr/mailcleaner/share/spamassassin --backup >/var/mailcleaner/spool/spamassassin/spamass_rules.bak
# backup Bogofilter bayes db
cp -a /root/.bogofilter/wordlist.db "/root/.bogofilter/$TIMESTAMP-wordlist.db"
if [ -f "/root/.bogofilter/$TIMESTAMP-wordlist.db.gz" ]
then
   rm -f "/root/.bogofilter/$TIMESTAMP-wordlist.db.gz"
fi
gzip "/root/.bogofilter/$TIMESTAMP-wordlist.db"

# get the spam and ham from the imap mailbox for the spamassassin and bogofilter db's
/opt/mailcleaner/scripts/imap-sa-learn.pl
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    (
      echo "Subject: Bogofilter database update $(hostname) failed"
      ls -l /var/mailcleaner/spool/bogofilter/database/
      ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $REPORT_EMAIL
    exit 1
fi

# copy the database to the right location
cp /root/.bogofilter/wordlist.db /var/mailcleaner/spool/bogofilter/database/wordlist.db
# If slave(s) Mailcleaner exists, ssh copy dbs to the slave(s)
#scp /root/.bogofilter/wordlist.db mailcleaner2.domain.com:/var/mailcleaner/spool/bogofilter/database/
#scp /var/mailcleaner/spool/spamassassin/spamass_rules.bak mailcleaner2.domain.com:/var/mailcleaner/spool/spamassassin/

# get the spam and ham counts from bogofilter - this just prints how many spam and ham you collected so far...
/opt/bogofilter/bin/bogoutil -w /var/mailcleaner/spool/bogofilter/database/wordlist.db .MSG_COUNT
```

Again thanks for the help.

Raj

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest just to use output redirection when you run the script:

```
./the_script.sh > /var/log/the_script.log 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` is to capture stderr (the error stream) as well as stdout (the output stream).

If you want to write a log file *and* see the output on the console, use `tee`:

```
./the_script.sh 2>&1 | tee /var/log/the_script.log
```

Comment: The script is in cron daily as a symbolic so not sure how I can do that can you advise pls.

Comment: You can write shell commands in crontabs. Just use a command line similar to the above.

Comment: If you have an example would be great, as i said my skills are very limited but willing to learn

Comment: Oh, I understand now what you were saying. You appear to be on a system with an `/etc/cron/daily` directory, which contains a symlink to this script. In that case, just replace the symlink by a simple wrapper script: `#!/bin/sh` <newline> `./the_script.sh 2>&1 | tee /var/log/the_script.log`. Remember to mark it executable with `chmod a+x`.

Comment: So the wrapper would look like

Comment: #!/bin/sh
./gethamspam.sh 2>&1 | tee /var/log/gethamspam.log

Comment: #!/bin/sh
/usr/mailcleaner/scripts/gethamspam.sh 2>&1 | tee /var/log/gethamspam.log

Comment: Why don't you just try it? The wrapper should just work when invoked from the command line, no need to wait for a day until cron runs it for you.